# Remove all posts from a Wordpress category but don't delete the post in MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have 2000 posts in a Wordpress category and I need to remove them. I don't want to delete the posts themselves, just remove the category from each post. I want to keep the category too but again zero it out.

I can do this with a bulk move plugin but it takes days ;) I've found MySQL queries to delete all posts from a category but I do not want to delete the post but move it from the category.

That being said, can anyone please help me with the MySQL statement that will remove all posts from a category without deleting the posts from other categories or the dB itself?

Thank you so so much!

**Edit: **

I found this:

```
update your_wp_prefix_term_relationships set
term_taxonomy_id=
(select term_taxonomy_id from your_wp_prefix_term_taxonomy where term_id=_ID_NEW_)
where
term_taxonomy_id=
(select term_taxonomy_id from your_wp_prefix_term_taxonomy where term_id=_ID_OLD_)
```

I changed the id new and id old vars to the correct category IDs and then ran it. I get the following error:

> #1146 - Table 'cust988_wp999.your_wp_prefix_term_relationships' doesn't exist

any ideas?

Comment: You'll have to change the `your_wp_prefix` to match the prefix you use in your installation

Comment: It\`s probably UPDATE `cust988_wp999_term_relationships`

Comment: It's always safer to use `$wpdb` to handle the prefixes. [Read more](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)